# Create a pattern regex to extract hour and minute from string in JAVA

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to make pattern which can give me hours and minute from a string in JAVA.
Whatever i try one or more example fails.

There can be below combination.

1. 1 hour
2. 2 hours
3. 1 hour 20 minutes
4. 3 hours 30 minutes
5. 3 hours 1 minute
6. 1 hour 1 minute
7. 1 minute
8. 10 minutes

   ```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\d]+)\\s+[hour|hours]*\\s*([\\d]*)[^\\d]*");


   Matcher m = p.matcher("8 hours 2 minutes");

   // if an occurrence if a pattern was found in a given string...
   if (m.find()) {
       System.out.println("found");
       System.out.println(m.group(1)); // hours
       System.out.println(m.group(2)); // minutes
   }
   ```

Comment: This isn't just an issue with your regex pattern. Your logic will need to run additional if statements for how many groups are matched and what's inside them.

Comment: Like how you are expecting your output from the above mentioned samples???

Comment: You've got some rethinking to do with your code but I'll give you this pattern to get you on the right track https://regex101.com/r/DNCYMl/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex, and extract hours and/or minutes from the appropriate group matched.

```
^(?=.)(?:(?<hours>\d+) *hours?)?(?: *(?<minutes>\d+) *minutes?)?$
```

Although I've named the groups to make it more easily accessible, but, it isn't really required so. Even without named groups, group1 will always capture hours and group2 will always capture minutes, no matter what your data contains, whether only hours or only minutes or both.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8kKku0/1)**

Also, checkout this Java code.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1 hour","2 hours","1 hour 20 minutes","3 hours 30 minutes","3 hours 1 minute","1 hour 1 minute","1 minute","10 minutes");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?=.)(?:(?<hours>\\d+) *hours?)?(?: *(?<minutes>\\d+) *minutes?)?$");

list.stream().forEach(x -> {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(x + " ----> Hours: " + m.group("hours") + ", Minutes: " + m.group("minutes"));
    } else {
        System.out.println(x + " ----> Didn't match");
    }
});
```

Prints,

```
1 hour ----> Hours: 1, Minutes: null
2 hours ----> Hours: 2, Minutes: null
1 hour 20 minutes ----> Hours: 1, Minutes: 20
3 hours 30 minutes ----> Hours: 3, Minutes: 30
3 hours 1 minute ----> Hours: 3, Minutes: 1
1 hour 1 minute ----> Hours: 1, Minutes: 1
1 minute ----> Hours: null, Minutes: 1
10 minutes ----> Hours: null, Minutes: 10
```

Comment: I would recommend starting the pattern with `^(?=.)` so it doesn't match empty strings.

Comment: @CAustin: Yes, that's a good point. Thanks for pointing out. Let me update my post with your suggestion. Although such kind of tight checks are needed more for validations of string but when it comes to just matching and extraction of strings, it isn't really required.